# Error Unable to detect manifest file. for JED - related to Folder permission

Tags: joomla-3.x, error-handling, jed

[image: the button in blue makes a message appear in red (horatio)]

Hello there On Joomla 3.9.26 stable i clicked on the blue Button up in the Image and then the red button above appeared.

I googled the error-message. I found something for joomla 1. and 2. but that does not help me.

I am using:

- Linux Raspberry 5. Firmware
- mysql
- mariaDB
- php 7.3
- Apache 2.4 (rasp)
- Joomla 3.9.26 Stable (armani)
- Joomla Platform 13.1.0
- Mozilla Firefoxy 84

does Joomla need some rights? the Joomla folder on the raspi is **chmod 755** according to an instruction. (I will check but I think it was Joomla forum).

Thanks in advance - have a great day or night.

PS: I followed folder permission [here](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=31832):
and I found this problem on **Folder Permission** which should be writeable:

[image: my not writeable folders]

And the user group is root root, i want to change this for my user name and joomla account is kamin-user. I will follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013286/create-new-ssh-user-account-to-access-specific-folder-only#1013289).

Comment: Thanks for the thumbs up. I followed the link instructions. When my Joomla Account is kamin-user  i might need www-data rigths (not so sure about that.) So chmod -R 775 and chown -R kamin-user:www-dat is what i am trying next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how i got green flags again.

1. first I added a user lets call him kamin-user

> sudo adduser --home /var/www/joomla --shell /bin/bash --no-create-home --ingroup www-data --ingroup ssh kamin-user

2. second I made a ownership with kamin-user and www-data important is only the www-data on second place (try and error) you can do root:www-data

> sudo chown -R kamin-user:www-data joomla/

3. third I did modify the permissions. (755 did not work)

> sudo chmod -R 775 joomla/

Lastly i don't know why this is needed and if that is a good setting. I will choose any answer that explains that a little. Or close it with this answer with in 2 Weeks.